# How to middle align through MigLayout

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, miglayout

I am creating a desktop application using swing and miglayout. How would I get the below gui? C1 being component 1.

```
+-----+ +-----+
| C1  | | C2  |
+-----+ +-----+ +----+
+-----+ +-----+ | C4 | 
| C3  | | C4  | +----+
+-----+ +-----+
```

Thank you.

Update with regards to the below answer.

[image]

Code is:

panel = new JPanel();

```
    MigLayout layout = new MigLayout("debug", "[][][]");
    panel.setLayout(layout);

    JCheckBox reptJCheckBox = new JCheckBox("REPT");
    JCheckBox tstcJCheckBox = new JCheckBox("TSTC");
    JCheckBox devJCheckBox = new JCheckBox("DEV");
    JCheckBox tstyCheckBox = new JCheckBox("TSTY");


    JButton openButton = new JButton("Open");

    panel.add(reptJCheckBox);
    panel.add(tstcJCheckBox, "wrap");
    panel.add(tstyCheckBox);
    panel.add(devJCheckBox);
    panel.add(openButton, "spany 2, wrap");
```

Comment: @Norman Arain you can also accept that answer to regards

Comment: I am showing that the code snippet provided is not working. I need a little more help please.

Comment: It doesn't work because you didn't follow the snippet correctly: 1) you have an extra `wrap` when adding `tstcJCheckBox` component. 2) `openButton` should be added in 3rd place (and not further) because it has to be located at 3rd column to properly span rows in that column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that you can't add the same component twice in a container, so having C1 and C2 tiwce is a mistake.

About components layout, I think the question is how to vertically center C3 component. Well this is the default behavior when you span rows using `spany` constraint: component gets vertically centered. Just try this snippet:

```
    MigLayout layout = new MigLayout("debug, fill", "[][][]");

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(layout);
    panel.add(new JButton("Button"));
    panel.add(new JButton("Button"));
    panel.add(new JButton("Button"), "spany 2, wrap");
    panel.add(new JButton("Button"));
    panel.add(new JButton("Button"));
```

#### Screenshot

[image]

#### Resource

See [MigLayout Quick Start Guide](http://www.miglayout.com/QuickStart.pdf) for further details about constraints.